# How Find this $f(x,y)$ such $f''_{xy}$ is not exsit.but $f_{xx}'',f_{yy}''$ is exsit.

Tags: analysis

**Question:**

**take example:such $f(x,y)$  in the unit disc $ D$ that extends continuously to ∂D**

> such that
>   $f_{xx}'',f''_{yy}$ exist,and  continuously,But $f''_{xy}(0,0)$ is not exsit.

**My try: I have consider sometimes,and I can't looking for this function $f(x,y)$ such this condition**.

**can anyone can help me? Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Extends continuously to $\partial D$" is quite irrelevant: we can always restrict the domain to a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and rescale.

Here is one example. Let $$f(x,y)= xy\sqrt{-\log(x^2+y^2)},\quad f(0,0)=0$$
Since the restriction of $f$ to either coordinate axis is identically zero, we have 
  $f_{xx}(0,0)=0$ and $f_{yy}(0,0)=0$. Also, the partial derivative
$$f_{xx}(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \cdot \frac{x^2-(x^2+3y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2) \log(x^2+y^2)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log(x^2+y^2)}}$$
tends to $0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, because the first two fractions are bounded. Thus, $f_{xx}$ is continuous. By symmetry, so is $f_{yy}$.

Yet, $f_x(x,0)=y\sqrt{-\log(y^2)}$ is not differentiable with respect to $y$ at $y=0$. Thus, $f_{xy}(0,0)$ does not exist. Neither does $f_{yx}(0,0)$, again by symmetry.

---

This kind of counterexample comes up in elliptic PDEs. See

- [Counterexample for the solvability of $-\Delta u = f$ for $f\in C^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304065/103254)
- [continuity and $C^2$ solution of a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155147/103254)